# Simple Probability

Tags: statistics, combinations, probability

Five U.S. Senators are selected at random from the 100 U.S. Senators. What is
the probability that at least two of the five selected are from the same state? There are 50 states, each with two senators.

Answer (score 0):

The probability that the second senator selected is not from the same state as the first is 98/99.

The probability that the third senator selected is not from the same states as the first two is 96/98.

The probability that the fourth senator selected is not from the same state as the first three is 94/97.

The probability that the fifth senator selected is not from the same state as the first four is 92/96.

Therefore the probability that all five senators are from different states 98*96*94*92/(99*98*97*96) =~ 0.90. In all other cases you get two or more from the same state, with a probability of ~0.10.

Comment: Thanks vince.. it was really very helpful... I was very confused with this question...